# Windows image in Azure Container Instances takes to long to start

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-container-instances

I tried creating a base Windows image (tag:2004) in Azure Container Instances and it took more than 10 minutes to start.

Is this normal? From what I've read it should take seconds to spin up a container.

Comment: Yes, Windows images are quite large.

Comment: Is there a way to cache the Windows image in Azure Container Instances?

Comment: Found this but I'm on a trial account and don't have a subscription so I can't see which images are cached. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/container-instances/location/list-cached-images?source=docs Is the Windows image cached in any location?

Answer (score 0):

**Since Window images is quite large it containe many software and file, This might take time to spin up**

**Yes ***[user238923](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/container-instances/location/list-cached-images?source=docs)***, You are on right ***[document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/container-instances/location/list-cached-images?source=docs)***, You can check window cache images in Azure Container Instance on specific location.**

***Cache window images in westcentralus location***

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, are there more cached images or just those you highlighted? Could you paste the whole output here or a pastebin?

Comment: Yes there are more cache images just pasting one more screenshot from bottom which showing linux images as well.